# Create indicator variable in load script

Tags: qlikview

I load the following input table

[image: input table]

through this script:

```
source_table:
Load company,
     product,
     sales
FROM source_file1.xlsx
```

I'd now like to create a table in script that looks like this:
[image: outputtable]

The column highest_selling is an indicator of the company that sells the most of this specific product. How can this be done? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Regards
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After loading the source.

```
source_table:
Load company,
     product,
     sales
FROM source_file1.xlsx
```

Then find the highest seller.

```
Highest:
Load product,
     max(sales) as Highest
resident source_table group by product;
```

Then join the highest indicator back onto the source table

```
left join (source_table)
load product,
     Highest as sales,
     1 as highest_seller
resident Highest; drop table Highest;
```